# Populating 2 Dimension VBA Array Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, for-loop, multidimensional-array

[image]

I've been somewhat stuck on creating and populating an array that takes each lineitem deposit in a row shown above and categorizes each deposit by the Acct listed under the Description Header.  There are 7 Columns depicted below.(7 Col)

The spreadsheet is updated daily and there can be up to 50,000 rows in an excel spreadsheet so "For Next" Loops aren't really optimal because after populating the Arrays by Acct Number, the next step is to Age the deposits by Date against the "Today's Date".

I get a result in the immediate window via debug.print, but the amts per Acct Number isn't adding up correctly.  I'm reaching out for help to see if anyone has any specific thoughts as to what I'm not getting here.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Option Base 1

Const MFGWholesale = 1628258400
Const DealerDirect= 8900504722
Const Retail = 8901054887
```

---

```
Sub AccumulativeSum()
Dim Dest As Range
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim ArrayMFG() As Variant, ArrayDD() As Variant, ArrayRetail() As Variant

Dim rcnt As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Trial")

'Turns off screen updating and auto calc to reduce process time
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

'unfilters if it's active BEFORE running the Array Process
If ws.FilterMode Then
    ws.ShowAllData
End If

rcnt = ws.Range("ColSeven").Rows.Count '<-- Initial Row Count of ColSeven Range
rCol = ws.Range("ColSeven").Value2 '< -- Value2 has it's advantages for arrays

'Resizing the Arrays
ReDim ArrayMFG(1 To rcnt, 1 To 7)
ReDim ArrayDD(1 To rcnt, 1 To 7)
ReDim ArrayRetail(1 To rcnt, 1 To 7)

'Group by Respective Bank Accts
For i = LBound(rCol, 1) To UBound(rCol, 1)

    If Len(rCol(i, 2)) <> 10 Then
        MsgBox "The Description for Cell: B" & i + 3 & " [Column B Row " & i + 3 & "] must include a 10 digit Acct Number"
        Exit Sub
    Else
    End If

    For j = LBound(rCol, 2) To UBound(rCol, 2)
        Select Case rCol(i, 2)
            Case MFGWholesale
                ArrayMFG(i, j) = rCol(i, 7) + ArrayMFG(i, 7)
            Case DealerDirect
                ArrayDD(i, j) = rCol(i, 7) + ArrayDD(i, 7)
            Case Retail
                ArrayRetail(i, j) = rCol(i, 7) + ArrayRetail(i, 7)
        End Select
    Next j
Next i

Dest.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ArrayMFG) 
Debug.Print Dest.Value
Dest.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ArrayDD)
Debug.Print Dest.Value
Dest.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ArrayRetail)
Debug.Print Dest.Value

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use a pivot table?

Comment: Yes, We could have the processor pivot table 50,000 line-item records in a new spreadsheet, but the data on this Sheet is in a workbook that I must be able to extract out of the Processor's File and place in a totally separate Aging Worksheet for Reporting Purposes to Directors at the Company.  After summarizing Deposits into 3 categories by the Acct Numbers listed, I then have to Age out the summarized Deps into Accounting Buckets based on the current date.  So, the 1st line item of $17,648.69 would be MFGWholesale Cat, 0~3 Day Bucket.  It's best it we do this via VBA

Comment: Sort your array on the date using a Quicksort UDF that uses recursivity.

Answer (score 0):

> I found the Answer by tinkering. Array( i , 2) where 2 represents the 2nd column in the Range which is what I wanted.  Thanxs for anyone considering an Answer.

```
For j = LBound(rCol, 2) To UBound(rCol, 2)
    Select Case rCol(i, 2)
        Case MFGWholesale
            ArrayMFG(i, 2) = rCol(i, 7) + ArrayMFG(i, 7)
        Case DealerDirect
            ArrayDD(i, 2) = rCol(i, 7) + ArrayDD(i, 7)
        Case Retail
            ArrayRetail(i, 2) = rCol(i, 7) + ArrayRetail(i, 7)
    End Select
Next j
```